# Why am I unable to save an existing user with updated attributes in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-console

I ran this in a rails console:

```
u = User.first
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 4, name: "Administrator", email: "administrator@wdis.com", created_at: "2013-09-27 01:01:54", updated_at: "2013-09-29 23:52:11", password_digest: ".......", remember_token: "........", admin: true, num_credits: nil> 
2.0.0p247 :002 > u.num_credits = 1
 => 1 
2.0.0p247 :003 > u.num_credits
 => 1 
2.0.0p247 :004 > u.save
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('administrator@wdis.com') AND "users"."id" != 4) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
 => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some validation which is stopping this user to be saved. Just check your validations in User model. You can also check the errors on this user using `u.errors.full_messages.to_sentence`

Comment: Thanks! It is telling me that "password is too short", which I had completely forgotten was a validation for existing users. Is it possible to have a validation that only runs when the password is being changed? This way the controller can change a field on user (in this case num_credits) without having to enter a password?

Comment: Done, any idea on my followup question?

Comment: You can restict the validation to occur on update or create or both but not on attribute change